# Is the Google Cloud Collective "on-topic" for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, scope, collectives

AFAIK: SO is primarily for programming and related questions. There has always been a grey area for DevOps and Cloud-based technologies, as long as an engineer is using them for development purposes we have been glad to provide help and support. I've taken advantage of this myself a few times during the years and I'm a prolific responder in the Docker and Kubernetes tags. Quite often though, people ask questions that are clearly purely network or router based, or purely cloud based with no connection to programming and I vote to close these as "professional server or networking related". There are better Stack Exchange forums for those questions where they will gain the attention of professionals in those areas.

Now a new feature, Collectives, has been released by SO's parent organisation, and while I support anything that generates revenue for them and which will eventually end up enriching our experience in SO, I'm not sure that the choices that have been made for the initial 'collectives' necessarily make sense within the confines of Stack Overflow. Obviously, GoLang is a natural fit and has every right to be here. But, Google Cloud?

I'm left wondering what the rest of the community think. Is Google Cloud really on-topic for SO? Yes, it's a grey area, and if treated correctly it could fit, but isn't it likely to just bring a whole host of "professional server or network related" questions?

To be clear, I'm happy with questions concerning APIs, terreform, DevOps, and other programming issues on GCP. But, Google Cloud is much bigger than that, and I'm wondering what everyone else thinks of this.

Comment: Google Cloud APIs are on-topic regardless of whatever gray area you feel like applying today

Comment: Are they? I missed that in the rules. Can you help with a reference please @Zoe? Also, I don't think this is just for API's is it? It may invite questions like how to configure a router for public access with dns through the UI

Comment: Calling APIs from code is programming, @SoftwareEngineer. I don't see how that could be off-topic for SO.

Comment: Any question about usage of APIs within a software development context is on-topic for Stack Overflow. That's been the case since day 1. Now, I think you do have some valid concerns that "Google Cloud" is a pretty broad name, and encompasses a number of things which *are* off-topic for Stack Overflow. We need to make sure that the expectations are clear.

Comment: Like I said @Mat, this isn't just API's is it?

Comment: DevOps stuff is less clear, but you can't just throw the whole lot out.

Comment: @Mat I'm not suggesting that we do. I think that Code Gray has a better handle on this. Google Cloud is broad, API's and a lot of DevOps is on-topic, but Google Cloud itself really isn't.

Comment: my problem is more with the nerving icon that appears to highlight the question, but the solution is simple down vote like hell

Comment: @nbk I don't think it would be fair to downvote a question because you don't like the icon, nor would it be fair to deny the org a chance to generate revenue.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer Teams is nt ncessary and doesn't bother , collectoves is not freely availbale who wants it and worksmlike an eliterian club membership, so as we can't hinder it, we can make it so that they give it up, some people get more downvotes, it is a fair price to pay

Comment: yeah, whatever we feel about the feature, it is not fair to users who give up their time to contribute (collective or not) if we vote not on the merits of the content - ends do not justify the means.

Comment: The guideline has always been there on Help Center long before Collectives: [Can I support my product on this site?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support).

Answer (score 20):

While many things about Google Cloud are not primarily about programming and thus off-topic, there is also a huge part of issues that do ultimately boil down to programming problems.

I think this is the perfect opportunity for Collectives to demonstrate whether they can work for topics that fall on the edge between on-topic and off-topic content.